# Escape characters in WMI namespace

Tags: powershell, reporting-services, wmi

I'm trying to find all instances of class `ReportServer_ConfigurationSetting` (configuration of SSRS) on local machine. This boils down to finding proper namespace and listing objects in it. I have no problems with it on most machines, but there is one catch. I do it using the following code:

```cs
function SSRS-GetInstanceNamespace($sqlInstanceName) {
    $ns = "Root\Microsoft\SqlServer\ReportServer\RS_${sqlInstanceName}"
    $ns = ($ns + '\' + (Get-WmiObject -Namespace $ns -Class __Namespace).Name + "\Admin")
    return $ns
}    
$x = (Get-ItemProperty 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server').InstalledInstances
$x | % { SSRS-GetInstanceNamespace $_ }
```

This works in most cases, but one of our machines has instance name that contains underscore, e.g. "A_B". Unfortunately since underscore is meaningful in WMI instance (at least it seems so), it has to be escaped. I can do it using simple replace, but is there any method that will consistently escape all special characters? In example above what I need is "A_5fB" instead of "A_B".

Comment: You could add `$sqlInstanceName = $sqlInstanceName -replace '_', '_5F'` as the first line in the `SSRS-GetInstanceNamespace` function.

Comment: As I wrote in my question this is exactly what I don't want to do. I want robust, future-proof solution.

Comment: Well.. as the underscore in a WMI query stands for _Any one character_ and you are using it as string literal in the instance name, you need to escape that by either putting it between square brackets `[_]` or by using the replace line in my previous comment. The only other "robust" way I can think of is by not using special characters in your instance names..

Comment: I don't think this is WMI query, since both: `get-wmiobject -class msreportserver_configurationsett
ing -namespace 'root\microsoft\sqlserver\reportserver\rs_A_B\V12\admin'` and `PS C:\Users\Administrator> get-wmiobject -class msreportserver_configurationsett
ing -namespace 'root\microsoft\sqlserver\reportserver\rs_A[_]B\V12\admin'` result in error, only `PS C:\Users\Administrator> get-wmiobject -class msreportserver_configurationsett
ing -namespace 'root\microsoft\sqlserver\reportserver\rs_A_5fB\V12\admin'` runs smoothly.

Comment: And not using underscore is not an option, it can be used and it will be used. Not by me, but by our customers most certainly. This happened more than once.

Comment: In that case, there is no escaping the fact that you need to escape..

Comment: That's right. And I don't know what characters except for underscore I should escape, so I thought that maybe there is some method around WMI that can be used to do it. I'd like to escape responsibility of maintaining it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never solved this problem the way I wanted to, I simply walk through the namespaces and recursively do:

```
get-wmiobject -namespace $ns -class __namespace
```

looking for those that match my criteria and try to match instance name using "heuristics", that is if it does not match directly then I try replacing `_` with `5F`. This works, but I'm basically certain that this will be a nice source of long stream of errors as more and more clients use this tool.